# Why a useful answer got deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, moderation

This was a hard to find solution that took me a few days to figure out. I have solved this issue before in my line of work, so I posted an answer so others can benefit. It started getting up votes and got even a +1 comment. Why in the world did it get deleted?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23964427/1084749

Please revive this answer!

Comment: Looks like a moderator oopsie there. Most likely the answer was flagged incorrectly and the moderator didn't see it was a genuine answer.

Comment: +1: Looks like an okay answer to me. I would also like to know why it was deleted.

Comment: I've flagged it for moderator attention, pointing to this meta post, asking for undeletion.

Comment: It is identical to [your previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019282/ignoring-android-lint-missingtranslation-check-for-partial-translations/23964406#23964406) (to a different question) which may play a part.

Comment: My answer applies to all the mentioned questions on the Lint suppression topic where I posted it. Those questions are not duplicates. But this answer does help solve all those issues. Please revive the answers so the public can see!

Comment: You lucky there is no duplicate flag on the comments yet...

Comment: While it didn't quite work out of the box - kudos for finding a solution to _a_ problem and looking for other questions to which it could apply.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I was not the moderator who deleted the answer but I understand why it was done.  You posted an identical answer to 5 questions which raised a flag to review the duplicate answers.

If you can use the identical answer across multiple posts, then that is a strong indicator that you have found duplicate questions.  Instead of posting the same answer you should vote to close these questions.

On the other hand, if you believe these are not duplicate questions then you should not be posting the exact same answer all of them and you should alter the answer to be specific to each problem asked.

Comment: My answer applies to all the mentioned questions on the Lint suppression topic where I posted it. Those questions are not duplicates. But this answer does help solve all those issues. Please revive the answers so the public can see!

Comment: @EduardK. Then as I said if you don't think they are duplicates then you should be making the answer specific to each question, copy/paste of an identical answer gives an indication that they are duplicate questions.

Comment: @EduardK. - I see you edited it, and given that people found value in this, I undeleted this answer.

Comment: I just went through and edited all of my answers. Can you please undelete them all. This one related to multiple annotations is still marked as deleted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459679/ignore-several-warnings-in-android-lint/23964450#23964450

Comment: And this one related to specific lint rules: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964489/how-to-add-suppress-lint-on-resources-xml-files/23964496#23964496

Comment: @EduardK. Done and done.  Thanks for taking the time to edit them to make each answer specific to the question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what about users that don't have the rep to close as duplicate?  Stuck at 1293 here :). Should I be flagging those, or just wait until I have the rep to vote?  If I should wait, can I gain easy rep and answer in an identical way?

Comment: @Matthew Flagging is the right thing to do, if they are actually duplicates. Otherwise, do what bluefeet et al. have suggested and *adapt* your answers to the specific question being asked.

Answer (score -7):

It should not have been deleted.  It was not a duplicate of any of the other answers, and isn't a low-quality answer.  Answers shouldn't be deleted just because they are used in more than one place, that is a natural phenomenon on this site; there are many duplicate AND non-duplicative questions that can be answered with the same answer.

Having said that, the best strategy is not to place all these answers at once, but place them out over time so that red flags aren't raised.

Comment: I agree. My answer applies to all the mentioned questions on the Lint suppression topic where I posted it. Those questions are not duplicates. But this answer does help solve all those issues. Please revive the answers so the public can see!

Comment: @EduardK.: then you'll have to edit your answers to each post to be specific to that post.

Comment: Spreading out answers over time won't work.  The system will still flag them as duplicates.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, ok, but it will cause the moderators to worry about them less if when they investigate the "duplicate" they don't see them all being posted in a short period of time.  The bottom line is that if his answer is right, then it shouldn't be shut down because he has used it more than once.  As dupes and similar questions increase on this site, we'll be seeing more of this.

Comment: The number of dupes does not matter, except insofar as a suspension might be warranted.  Nor does the length of time between dupes.  A dupe is a dupe.