# How to have a deleted answer reviewed/disputed?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-answers, duplicate-answers

I had an answer deleted by a moderator [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212228/boot2docker-on-mac-accessing-local-files/33404182?noredirect=1#comment54700327_33404182) because I used the same answer for two questions. Those questions are slightly different, but the answers to them are the same. My answer is the one I wish I had found to both questions, and it will help anyone having the issue in the future.

It looks like the answer was deleted by a single moderator and there is no way to dispute it. I've even modified it so it's tailored to the question more. What should I do? This feels like a silly abuse of moderator power to me.

Original answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439126/how-to-mount-host-directory-in-docker-container/33404132#33404132).

Here's a screenshot of the deleted answer for those below 10k points who can't see it:

[image: screenshot of deleted answer]

Comment: What was the original answer so that we could compare & contrast?

Comment: Are they different in a *significant* way? Why didn't you tailor them to the specific question then?

Comment: If a diamond deleted it, the only way to get it back is to raise a custom flag on it asking for it to be undeleted. No one else can get it back for you. That said, if you used the same _exact_ answer for 2 questions, don't expect it to get undeleted.

Comment: If it was really the SAME answer, you should've answered one and duped the other

Comment: @Makoto added. Deduplicator, theB, Patrice: as mentioned in the post, the QUESTIONS are different even though the answer is the same to both questions. It's like if someone asked "what's 4-2" and someone else asked "what's 3-1." The answer to both is "2" but they are not the same question.

Comment: Questions are indeed different so dupe flag won't help. And if the answer solves the problem why delete it?

Comment: [Does the same answer imply that the questions should be closed as duplicate?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292329/does-the-same-answer-imply-that-the-questions-should-be-closed-as-duplicate)

Comment: Direct link to the [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292331/5240004) left by the same mod that deleted the answer here.

Comment: Interesting. Despite more than 2x the number of people voting that it's perfectly reasonable to have the same answer to two different questions, ChrisF continues to go around deleting answers just for this reason. What's the StackExchange way to settle stuff like this? Can it be raised for a vote somewhere?

Comment: @Eli: Did you read all the qualifications in which that is couched?

Comment: @Deduplicator yes. Is there one in particular you're referring to?

Comment: Well, summarizing that post: An identical answer is a very good indicator that the questions aren't significantly different and should be closed as duplicates. If they aren't, it's unlikely the same answer would be a *good* answer to both; there's just about always *something* in the explanation or elaboration which should be customized. Or at least there's something which *could* be to make them better. Resolve your case like the OP there did, it had a happy outcome.

Comment: @Eli It might help people get on board if you could explain how the two questions are in fact not the same. To me, they appear to be asking the same thing, but then again I don't use Docker. So what is the significant difference between [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212228/boot2docker-on-mac-accessing-local-files) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26348353/mount-volume-to-docker-image-on-osx)?

Comment: @Louis one question is explicitly about boot2docker. The other is asking about mounting volumes in Docker in general.

Comment: @theB the actual answer to my question is what you mentioned: "raise a custom flag on it asking for it to be undeleted." If you add that as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it correct.

Comment: Perhaps later you could make your case over at [my request for examples where identical answers do not mean duplicate questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267318/are-there-any-non-trivial-examples-of-exact-duplicate-answers-to-non-duplicate-q).

Comment: Seriously? 11 downvotes without a single person explaining why this is a bad question?

Comment: @Eli: It's not a bad question, but it's likely most of the downvoters just don't think this is a situation that warrants reversing the mod's decision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your answer was deleted by a moderator (♦), so can only be undeleted by a moderator. If you believe that the two answers are different enough that it warrants undeletion, then the only way to have it undeleted is to flag it for moderator attention.

That said, it probably won't get undeleted in its current state, where the majority part of the answer is an exact match. Why do I say that?

bluefeet♦ at [Why a useful answer got deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256849/5240004):

> If you can use the identical answer across multiple posts, then that is a strong indicator that you have found duplicate questions. Instead of posting the same answer you should vote to close these questions.

Jon Clements♦ in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307311/if-a-duplicate-is-suspected-shouldnt-moderators-close-questions-as-such-instea/307317#comment253933_307311)

> Then the exact same answer probably isn't appropriate then? If you don't think the questions are duplicates, then amend your answer to be specific to each question as appropriate - don't just copy/paste the same answer

ChrisF♦ in an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307313/5240004) referencing Jon's comment:

> As Jon points out in his comment, if the questions aren't duplicates then you should be tailoring your answer to the specifics of the question.

George Stocker♦ in an answer to [Why were my answers deleted? [...]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278125/5240004):

> If you see two questions that are so similar that you believe the same answer applies, your best bet is to vote to close or flag to close the question as a duplicate.
>
> If you do not have the reputation to do that, either tailor your answer to the specific question asked, or leave a comment pointing to your answer.

Robert Harvey♦ in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268569/is-there-any-possible-thing-to-do-if-i-strongly-disagree-with-a-moderator#comment77295_268570):

> The moderator has a point; it's not acceptable to copy/paste a general answer to several specific questions. That's backwards. The right way is to post the general answer to a general question about packaging, or whatever this is about.

BoltClock♦ in an answer to [What should be done about the recycling of incorrect answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270223/5240004)

> As you may have guessed, we don't delete incorrect answers, but if someone is bumping several questions with what is essentially the same answer when they should be flagging the questions as duplicates instead, we may speak to them.

*(I'm sure that if I dig a little I could probably find more.)*

Comment: If anyone quoted above feels that I misquoted them, or wants to add some more information, feel free to edit it in.